# Batch class approach restrict multiple email

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, singleemailmessage, set

I have a requirement to send mails some Users (DM lookup ids) notified about creation of records in a custom object based on a specific filter criteria. Now if there are records in different batches having records pointed to same Users (DM lookups), multiple notifications those users will receive. I need to restrict that. If first batch has a record with the User, ignore that in second.I have my code here. Can someone suggest an approach?

code:

```
global class Incidentimp_2 implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    public String[] fil = new String[] {'Closed'};
    public string query = 'SELECT DM_Lookup_id__c FROM Incident__c where createddate=today and Status_abv__c not in : fil';

    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Incident__c> scope) {

        Set<ID> IdSet = new Set<ID> {};

        for (Incident__c so : scope) {
            IdSet.add(so.DM_Lookup_id__c);
        }

        List<User> usr = [select Email, id, Name from User where id in:IdSet];
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr.size());
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr);
        for (User u : usr) {
            String plainTextBody = '';
            plainTextBody += 'Dear ' + u.Name + '\n';
            plainTextBody += 'New non-compliant cases have been assigned to you in Aspire. \n';
            plainTextBody += 'Please review and resolve all issues within two weeks.\n\n';



            // String plaintxtbody = String.join(txtbody, '/n');

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new String[] {u.email});
            email.setccAddresses(new String[] {'saikat.neogy@cognizant.com'});
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            //email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
            email.setPlainTextBody(plaintextbody);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        }


    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Database.Stateful interface (see doc [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm))

Then you can use a

> global Set < Id>  sUsersSentEmail

variable and every time you need to sent an email to a User

- Check if the id exists in the Set.
- If Yes Skip
- If no send the email and add the User.Id to the Set

> ```
>     global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Incident__c> scope) {
> ```

```
        Set<ID> IdSet = new Set<ID> {};

        for (Incident__c so : scope) {
            IdSet.add(so.DM_Lookup_id__c);
        }

        List<User> usr = [select Email, id, Name from User where id in:IdSet];
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr.size());
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr);
        for (User u : usr) {
            /****** ADD THIS PIECE OF CODE *****/
            if (sUsersSentEmail.contains(u.Id))
               continue;
            sUsersSentEmail.add(u.id);
            /*************/

            String plainTextBody = '';
            plainTextBody += 'Dear ' + u.Name + '\n';
            plainTextBody += 'New non-compliant cases have been assigned to you in Aspire. \n';
            plainTextBody += 'Please review and resolve all issues within two weeks.\n\n';



            // String plaintxtbody = String.join(txtbody, '/n');

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new String[] {u.email});
            email.setccAddresses(new String[] {'saikat.neogy@cognizant.com'});
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            //email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
            email.setPlainTextBody(plaintextbody);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
        }


    }
```

Hopefully you don't have that many Users to hit the Heap size limit ;-)

Comment: Hi ManSpan! Thanks but once a batch of say 200 records is run it will go till sending mail. Then in batch 2 whether I add the id or not doesn't matter because sets are unique and it will send mails to whole set again. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's not clear what I suggest. You use the set i proposed, as a filter. So if in Batch 1 you send an email to user 005a then you add 005a to the set. In Batch 2 your check if ( sUsersSentEmail.contains(User.Id)) will return true and then you skip. See my edited post

Comment: I am sorry ManSpan! I understand your way but I am unable to correlate them in two different for loops. Can you please place that here in code?

Comment: see my updated post plz

Comment: Hi ManSpan! where do you populate static Set < Id> sUsersSentEmail ?

Comment: it needs to be global sorry... I usually initialise it in the constructor method of the Batch Class.

Comment: But I can't understand how values are getting into sUsersSentEmail SET?

Comment: sUsersSentEmail.add(u.id);

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by making a batch stateful. When using Database.Stateful, the instance member variables retain their values between transactions. You can do the following:
- Make the batch Stateful
- Declare a list as an instance member of the class
- Populate that list in execute method
- Send the email in FINISH method

For example:

```
global class Incidentimp_2 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
  Set<ID> IdSet = new Set<ID> {};
    public String[] fil = new String[] {'Closed'};
    public string query = 'SELECT DM_Lookup_id__c FROM Incident__c where createddate=today and Status_abv__c not in : fil';

    global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Incident__c> scope) {

        //

        for (Incident__c so : scope) {
            IdSet.add(so.DM_Lookup_id__c);

        }


        }


    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
List<User> usr = [select Email, id, Name from User where id in:IdSet];
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr.size());
        System.debug ('List size: ' + usr);
        for (User u : usr) {
            String plainTextBody = '';
            plainTextBody += 'Dear ' + u.Name + '\n';
            plainTextBody += 'New non-compliant cases have been assigned to you in Aspire. \n';
            plainTextBody += 'Please review and resolve all issues within two weeks.\n\n';



            // String plaintxtbody = String.join(txtbody, '/n');

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            email.setToAddresses(new String[] {u.email});
            email.setccAddresses(new String[] {'saikat.neogy@cognizant.com'});
            email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            //email.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
            email.setPlainTextBody(plaintextbody);
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});
    }

}
```